# Issues while Loading data from HDFS to Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

**Scenario 1 :**
Provided the custom location while creating the table in hive and then using 'copy from local' command to load the data.
Below process is directly loading the data into my table.
But Scenario 2 is not working when i'm using the default location to load data using the 'copy from local' command. As it is executing without any error but not loading my table.

Below link for Scenario 1 Commands---

[Scenario 1 Commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbEr7.png)-- this is loading the data into the table.

[Scenario 2 Commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzV7e.png)-- replacing the Scenario 1 Location path to default hive path -- but data is not loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below command to find the exact location to which the files needs to be copied

```
hive -e 'describe formatted Employee'
```

If you have created the table in the default DB then the location will be

```
/user/hive/warehouse/default.db/Employee
```

Incase you have to copy the file to that folder

```
hadoop fs -put /home/weirdo/sample.txt /user/hive/warehouse/default.db/Employee/.
```

Note : If you are going to create a partitioned table then copying it to the partitioned folder wont be enough. need to execute `msck repair table Employee` to add the partition information to the hive metastore

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy into the database's table directory, not just the Hive warehouse directory

There's not much of an advantage to using a location vs not, in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

#### Scenario 2:

your are just creating a table , So if you are not using location keyword, database will be created in default warehouse directory

```
 /user/hive/warehouse
```

In order to load data in 2nd case

you have to copy data file from local path to hive default directory(or any hdfs path), Later you have to use load command to load the data manually.(even you can load data from local path also)

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '<file_path>' INTO TABLE <table_name>
```

or

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '<hdfs_file_path>' INTO TABLE <table_name>
```

(we can copy the data using copy from local command).

Comment: is it because of default directory??

Comment: no, nothing like that. if you give location then only it will load the data else you have to load it manually

Comment: @pooja patil If you are loading through some mapreduce job or something you can use the manual step finding the path what ive mentioned in the answer below.